# How to exclude sheets from a script

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pause

I wrote a simple script to automatically sort new input in various sheets, but I would like to exclude the two first sheets. Here's my script:

```
function onEdit(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sh.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();

  if(editedCell == 2) { 

    var range = sh.getRange("A3:P20");
    range.sort({column: 2});
  }
}
```

So if I use .getActiveSheet() while working on the first two sheets, the script wil do it's job, but unwanted. Can I stop the script, put on pause? 
Thanks for a reply. 
Tony

Comment: Hi i dunno exactly what you try to do, an overwrite "hook" the function and or add at first line return false; to stop the job.

Answer (score 0):

This will keep you from using the first two sheets.  You could also use their names because if you move them then the first two sheets will change.  The function isOneOfTheFirstTwo is explained below:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(!isOneOfFirstTwo(e.source.getActiveSheet()))
  {
    var editedCell = sh.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();
    if(editedCell == 2) 
    { 
      var range = sh.getRange("A3:P20");
      range.sort({column: 2});
    }
  }
}
```

The below function gets the array of all sheets from the spreadsheet and looks at the first two which are the first two sheets on the left side of the spreadsheet.  If you move them then the first two sheets will change.  Any way I look only and the first two and ask the question is sh.getName() == allSheets[i] if either of the first two answer yes then function returns true other wise it returns false.  The loop doesn't go past the first two sheets.

```
function isOneOfFirstTwo(sh)
{
  var allSheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var r=false;
  for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    if(sh.getName()==allSheets[i].getName())
    {
      r=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer.
I'm really a novice and tried to put your code into mine, but I get a fault whilst debugging. Would it be possible to put your script completely in mine. I think I made mistakes trying to get it in.

```
function isOneOfFirstTwo(sh)
{
  var allSheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var r=false;
  for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    if(sh.getName()==allSheets[i].getName())
    {
      r=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function onEdit(){
   if(!isOneOfFirstTwo(e.source.getActiveSheet()))
  {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sh.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();

  if(editedCell == 2) { 

    var range = sh.getRange("A3:P20");
    range.sort({column: 2});
  }
 }
}
```